# Creating a user profile and groups with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, profile

I am wondering what is the best practice to create a user profile and groups in rails. Where a user has profile and can create groups. Should i go with scaffolding ? If not, how do i do it some other way ?

Thanks :)

Comment: <p>
Also what about the routes. What if i want to have something like - `localhost:3000/UserName` and not `localhost:3000/user/1` </p>

Comment: Scaffolding creates models, views & controllers for a new resourse in single operation. It doesn't really hinder your requirements here, rather make it more simpler.

Comment: yes i know. But then should i go with scaffolding or should i go ahead create sepearte models ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be good to check the excellent "Rails 3 tutorial" by Hartl, it builds a twitter-like application in the tutorial, and explains in details the creation of a user profile model with groups of followers, followed. You can then later adapt the app to your needs, but it's a very very good tutorial, you won't waste your time.